# How to return nested JSON?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have 3 table in **PostgreSQL** database.

**QUESTIONS** table:

```
| id (int) | text (text)                          |
|----------|--------------------------------------|
| 1        | What is your favorite color?         |
| 2        | What is your favorite football club? |
```

**OPTIONS** table:

```
| id (int) | text (text) |
|----------|-------------|
| 1        | red         |
| 2        | blue        |
| 3        | grey        |
| 4        | green       |
| 5        | brown       |
```

**QUESTIONS_OPTIONS** table:

```
| question_id (int) | option_id (int) |
|-------------------|-----------------|
| 1                 | 1               |
| 1                 | 2               |
| 1                 | 3               |
| 1                 | 4               |
| 1                 | 5               |
```

In Golang application I create such models:

```
type Option struct {
    ID   int    `json:"option_id"`
    Text string `json:"option_text"`
}

type Question struct {
    ID int `json:"question_id"`
    Text string `json:"question_text"`
    Options []Option `json:"options"`
}
```

In controller I have such code:

```
var GetQuestions = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    rows, _ := database.DBSQL.Query("SELECT * FROM questions;")
    defer rows.Close()

    var questions []Question

    for rows.Next() {
        var question Question
        var options []Option

        queries, _ := database.DBSQL.Query(`select options.id as option_id, options.text as option_text from questions_options inner join questions on questions_options.question_id = ` + &question.ID + ` inner join options on questions_options.option_id = options.id`)
        queries.Close()

        for queries.Next() {
            var option Option
            if err := queries.Scan(&option.ID, &option.Text); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            options = append(options, option)
        }

        if err := rows.Scan(&question.ID, &question.Text, options); err != nil {  // service raise error in this line: sql: expected 2 destination arguments in Scan, not 3
            log.Println(err)
        }

        questions = append(questions, question)
    }
    utils.Response(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, questions)
}
```

When I try to make GET request to take all questions with all there options service such incorrect result:

```
[
    {
        "question_id": 0,
        "question_text": "",
        "options": null
    },
    {
        "question_id": 0,
        "question_text": "",
        "options": null
    }
]
```

Where I make mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `queries.Close()` to the end of loop, like this:

```
var GetQuestions = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    rows, _ := database.DBSQL.Query("SELECT * FROM questions;")
    defer rows.Close()

    var questions []Question

    for rows.Next() {
        var question Question

        if err := rows.Scan(&question.ID, &question.Text); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        queries, _ := database.DBSQL.Query(`select options.id as option_id, options.text as option_text from questions_options inner join questions on questions_options.question_id = $1 inner join options on questions_options.option_id = options.id`, question.ID)

        for queries.Next() {
            var option Option
            if err := queries.Scan(&option.ID, &option.Text); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            question.Options = append(question.Options, option)
        }
        queries.Close()

        questions = append(questions, question)
    }
    utils.Response(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, questions)
}
```

Comment: Hello! I also tried it. It don't work. My IDEA say such warning: `Possible resource leak, 'defer' is called in a for loop`. As you can see in code I have such code: `rows.Scan(&question.ID, &question.Text, options)` Something wrong with 3rd argument. In console I see error like this: `sql: expected 2 destination arguments in Scan, not 3`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: place queries.Close() after for {}

Comment: I did it right now. The same incorrect result. I think problem is here  `rows.Scan(&question.ID, &question.Text, options)`. Any  ideas?

Comment: If I remove wrote like this: `rows.Scan(&question.ID, &question.Text)` it show me id and text correctly in JSON result but `options` field return `null`.

Comment: please, take a look in fixed answer, I changed queries scan

Comment: Can you check your code one more time? It seems to me that this part `question.options = append(question.options, option)` is not correct. Maybe syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, should be: question.Options = append(question.Options, option)

Comment: It show me the same options to both question. In fact first question has 3 option and second question don't have any option.

Comment: It seems to me that `&question.ID` variable inside SQL statement is syntactically wrong. What you think about that?

Comment: I changed it to `strconv.Itoa(question.ID)`. Now it works.

Comment: Fixed query, but I not 100% sure in query with part of `$1`